# How to convert first 15 characters in a char array to std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I know I can convert character arrays to `std::string` using: `string str(array);`

But the question is: Could take part of it and convert to string? (for example, first 15 characters)

By the way, my array is defined on the stack.

Thanks.

Comment: _"...to string in C ?"_  Why C++ then ?

Comment: use the other constructor

Comment: `charArray[15] = 0;`  Then do whatever string conversion you want.

Answer (score 7):

You use the constructor that takes two iterators (pointers, which arrays decay to, model Random Access Iterators):

```
std::string str(array, array+15);
```

This way you can take any part of the array, not just first 15 characters.

Comment: Beat me by 4 seconds, and you've got an explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a `char` array, use the [`std::string`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), which takes 2 iterators:

```
std::string str(arr, arr + 15);
```

In case you have an instance of `std::string` already, use `std::string::substr`:

```
std::string str("my long string full of words");
std::cout << "'" << str.substr(0,15) << "'";
```

outputs: `'my long string '`

Comment: I think OP has a `char` array